# Is it possible to bring in Payment Status and Fulfilment status from Shopify to NetSuite?

Tags: shopify, netsuite

I have a Shopify site that is connected to NetSuite using a NS Connector called 'FarApp'.

At the moment, I have set it to only import orders that have been marked as 'Paid' or 'Authorized' so that we can fulfil those orders using NetSuite.

As a rule, the company doesn't fulfil orders until the order is completely paid for, shipping is completely organized with a shipping company and the items picked up for shipping.

I've been told that we cannot import the Payment Status nor Shipping status for each order on Shopify. Is it possible we could have a flag for those orders on NetSuite if I imported those orders as well?

Is there another connector that can be able to do that?

Any help or guidance would be appreciated. TIA

Answer (score 0):

NetSuite infers Payment Status and Shipping Status based on the presence and status of an invoice and item fulfillment, respectively.  That's why you cannot explicitly set these during import.

You should be able to create a Payment Event in the order when you import it, and check Record External Event to let NetSuite know the payment has been collected elsewhere.  You could then create a cash sale based on the order using `Record.transform()`.  Exact details will vary depending on how the connector is set up, and your business rules.

> Is it possible we could have a flag for those orders on NetSuite if I imported those orders as well?

Not sure exactly what you mean here, but you could create a custom checkbox field called something like "Shopify Order" and set the connector to always set this to true to explicitly identify those imported orders.